# Python: How to use the "sum" function to calculate the sum of numbers in a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the sum of multiple numbers in one list, but there always appears an error.
These numbers are readed from a txt.

Numbers:

```
19.18,29.15,78.75,212.10
```

My code:

```
infile = open("January.txt","r")
list = infile.readline().split(",")
withdrawal= sum(list)
```

Error:

```
withdrawal= sum(list)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: You are not converting your numbers from the string in text to a numerical format, e.g. float or integers. Have a look at what is inside your variable `list`, you will see the type will not be integers or floats.

Comment: Please be sure that your numbers in the list are all integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to convert each element from `str` to `float`, you can do this with a generator expression.

```
with open("January.txt","r") as infile:
    data = infile.readline().split(",")
    withdrawal = sum(float(i) for i in data)
```

Comment: I am a python beginner, thank you for your answer, which is very helpful to me!

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the list are in `str` format. When they are converted into `int` or `float` format, then the `sum function` will return the sum of the list.

This can be done using the `map function` as following:

```
liss=map(float,lis)
```

Hence :

```
f=open("January.txt", "r")
lis = f.readline().split(",")
liss=map(float,lis)
withdrawal= sum(liss)
print(withdrawal)
```

This will produce the desired output.

Hope this was helpful!